# Formatting a string in delphi

Tags: delphi

I want to update a text like "Updating report (1 0f 5)". I thought format function will help me to do that. I want something like this

```
string := Format('Updating report ( %d of %d, [1], [2])', loop, count );
```

but it is not possible. I have an option to have loop and count stored in a string and concatenate everything. But is there any other way to achieve what i want?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your syntax is wrong. The second parameter to the [`Format`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.SysUtils.Format) is an open array containing the arguments. So you need to wrap your list of arguments in what is known as an [open array constructor](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Calling_Procedures_and_Functions#Open_Array_Constructors).

> An open array constructor is a sequence of expressions separated by commas and enclosed in brackets.

So, write the code like this:

```
str := Format('Updating report (%d of %d)', [loop, count]);
```